# Is it possible to show WebRTC peers only from a local network?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, lan, signaling

It's more of a signaling issue than WebRTC, but is it somehow possible to find computers only within the same local network? E.g. would it be possible to create a service similar to OS X AirDrop, where you could go to page e.g. https://airdrop.com and you would see other computers that also have the same site opened in the browser, but *only* if they are in the same local network without having to host some kind of signalling server *within* the local network (i.e. having only one "global" signaling server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all computers in the local network have access to the Internet through a single device, all of them will have the same public IP.

Then, in your server, you only have to look at the IP.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to connect without signaling server at all if I know local IP addresses of the computers I'd like to connect to?